# How do I select a class in a span with CSS?

Tags: html, css, class, mobile

I want to not display an icon for the mobile menu. But I'm not sure how to select this class. It's inside a menu.

```
 <a class="funiter-menu-item-title" title="Nieuw">Nieuw<span class="icon fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

I want to select this icon and not display it on the mobile version. Does anyone knows the solution?

```
<span class="icon fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly:

```
a.funiter-menu-item-title > span.icon.fa.fa-chevron-down {
    display: none;
}
```

Or if you have access to the html code, add custom class to the element that you want to hide, as example below:

```
<a class="funiter-menu-item-title" title="Nieuw">Nieuw<span class="elementToHide icon fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>

a.funiter-menu-item-title > span.elementToHide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Egad! What a selector: `a.funiter-menu-item-title > span.icon.fa.fa-chevron-down`. Same is achieved with `.funiter-menu-item-title .fa-chevron-down`, overly specific selectors could become problematic at some point.